# How can I remove the comment form on one or more specific pages in twenty eleven?

Tags: comment-form

I would like to remove the comment form on one specific page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can disable comments for individual pages from ***dashboard - pages - all pages***: 
click ***quick-edit*** below the page name, then untick ***allow comments*** 
- that should remove the comment form from the page.